# What would be faster in this context String.Format or String.Replace?

Tags: c#, string, string-formatting, stringbuilder

```
string str = 'my {0} long string {1} need formatting';
```

Should I be doing the following,

```
str = string.Format(str, "really", "doesn't");
```

or creating a method like so and calling `str = str.ReplaceWithValues("really", "doesn't");`

```
 public string ReplaceWithValues(this string str, params object[] values) {
    string ret = str;
    for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++) {
        ret = str.Replace(string.Concat("{", i, "}"), values.ToString());
    }
    return ret;
}
```

It seems like StringBuilder.AppendFormat() isn't efficient when it comes to doing simple replacements like this since it goes character by character through the string.

Comment: Do you need such a extreme performance tuning or you are just curious?

Comment: @Claudio Redi - I'm just curious.

Comment: "It seems like `StringBuilder.AppendFormat()` isn't efficient when it comes to doing simple replacements like this since it goes character by character through the string."  What do you think `string.Replace` does?

Comment: Nitpicking: `string str = '...'` should use double quotes.

Comment: @Nelson: While you're at it - the method needs to be "static", since it's an extension method, too ;)

Comment: @Reed - True, I hadn't gotten that far.  And I'm guessing `values.ToString()` should be `values[i].ToString()`.  Also, doing `string ret = str;` is unnecessary and creates another copy of the immutable string.  And looking further, only the last value will actually be replaced in the return string.  `ret = str.Replace(...)` keeps overwriting `ret`, losing the previously replaced string.

Comment: @all - working on a site in php right now, and was just trying to get the point across... you guys are just trying to hurt my code's feelings. It might not be as fast as the rest of the codes out there, and it might not get all the answers right, but that doesn't give you the right to make fun of it. :D

Comment: Yeah, that's why I said I was nitpicking first, but then it got out of hand. :)  I think you got your point across.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Why do you want to reinvent String.Format?

I'd just use the framework method - it does exactly what you want, is robust, and is going to make sense to those that follow...

---

Just to satisfy your curiousity:

> It seems like StringBuilder.AppendFormat() isn't efficient when it comes to doing simple replacements like this since it goes character by character through the string.

String.Format, FYI, uses StringBuilder.AppendFormat internally.  That being said, StringBuilder.AppendFormat is quite efficient.  You mention that it goes "character by character" through the string - however, in your case, you're using multiple calls to Replace and Concat instead.  A single pass through the string with a StringBuilder is likely to be much quicker.  If you really need to know- you could profile this to check.  On my machine, I get the following timings if I run both of the above 1,000,000 times:

```
String.Format -  1029464 ticks
Custom method -  2988568 ticks
```

Comment: I'm just curious. Not anything that is planning to go into development.

Comment: @Jeremy: I just edited my answer to help your curiosity - as you can see, the framework method is better on just about every count. ;)

Comment: Just did 100 iterations of 10k of each, and my custom method is 1/2 the speed. Which is weird after looking at StringBuilder.AppendFormat()'s code.

Answer (score 2):

The custom procedure will increase its cost with each additional placeholder and produce throwaway strings for the garbage collector with each intermediate call to `Replace`.

Besides the likelihood that `string.Format` is much faster than multiple calls to `Replace`, `string.Format` includes overloads to culture-sensitive operations as well.

The flexibility and intuitiveness of `string.Format` is at least as compelling as the speed.

Answer (score 1):

If all you want is to concatenate some strings, why not just do that?

```
string result = "my " + x + " long string " + y + " need formatting";
```

or

```
string result = string.Concat("my ", x, " long string ", y, " need formatting");
```

Comment: Same reason anyone uses string.Format... it is cleaner looking than a bunch of concats.

Comment: +1 This is the fastest solution - `string.Concat` uses unmanaged methods internally to create an new string.

Comment: In your example it's not too bad, but it gets hairy with some more complex strings: `"[{0}] {1}: {2}."` becomes `"[", x, "] ", y, ": ", z, "."`.  Or with quotes: `"attr1=\"{0}\" attr2=\"{1}\""` becomes `"attr1=\"", x, "\" attr2=\"", y, "\""`.  Which is clearer?  Then you can add formatting like `{0:C}` which also simplifies it further.

Answer (score 0):

In C# the + operator actually turns in to a string.Concat(), and I always thought `String.Format("Hello: {0} {1}", "Bob", "Jones")` was the fastest.  It turns out, after firing up a sample ran outside the debugger, in release mode, that `"Bob" + "Jones"` is much faster.  There is a cutoff point though.  I believe around 8 concatenations or so, string.Format becomes faster.

Comment: I think that's because `"Bob" + "Jones"` will be optimized to `"BobJones"` in compile time in Release mode